# Updating local database constantly VS writing data into a file constantly

Tags: database, sqlite, local-storage, storage, file-writing

I am in situation where i am supposed to write data into some sort of storage constantly (Almost less than a second or close to a second). I am not sure what to use for this purpose. I was in favor of local database (SQlite) as i can arrange things better this way. However, i am not sure if it is fast enough to update data in database constantly. Is writing data to a file is better than using database?

Comment: it depends on what data you want to write, if they are just string or values then you should store them in local db, if they are images or binary data, you should store them in the file system.

Comment: Well most of the data is string. I don't think i am going to store any binary data. Will database's constant updates be faster than file writing?

Comment: database's constant updates is faster than file writing

Comment: I will give database a go then thanks @Capitaine

Answer (score 1):

Database would be a better option for obvious reasons (speed or reading/writing/modifying data). Well, I would suggest to go with `MongoDB` as you've stated that you need to write/modify data in db , moreover your data is simple i-e no complex relations (if this is the case), I would suggest to go with `MongoDB` on `SQlite`. As, reading/modification of data is really good in terms of performance on `MongoDB`. As explained [here](http://hammerprinciple.com/databases/items/sqlite/mongodb). (specific to read/modification of the data).